# Potential on a quiver

Tags: rt.representation-theory, definitions, quivers

I found two definitions of potential on a quiver.

> [Selfinjective quivers with potential and 2-representation-finite algebras, Martin Herschend and Osamu Iyama](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.1917.pdf) **2.1 Quivers with potential.** Let $Q$ be a quiver. We denote by $\widehat{K Q}$ the complete path algebra and by $J_{\widehat{K Q}}$ the Jacobson radical of $\widehat{K Q}$. Then $\widehat{K Q}$ is a topological algebra with $J_{\widehat{KQ}}$-adic topology. We denote
> $$
> \operatorname{com}_{Q}:=\overline{[\widehat{K Q}, \widehat{K Q}]} \subset \widehat{K Q}
> $$
> where $\overline{()}$ denotes the closure. Then $\widehat{K Q} / \operatorname{com}_{Q}$ has a topological basis consisting of cyclic paths considered up to cyclic permutation. Thus, there is a unique continuous linear map
> $$
> \sigma: \widehat{K Q} / \operatorname{com}_{Q} \rightarrow \widehat{K Q}
> $$
> induced by $a_{1} \cdots a_{n} \mapsto \sum_{i} a_{i} \cdots a_{n} a_{1} \cdots a_{i-1}$ for all cycles $a_{1} \cdots a_{n}$. For each $a \in Q_{1}$, define the continuous linear maps
> $$
> L_{a^{-1}}, R_{a^{-1}}: J_{\widehat{K Q}} \rightarrow \widehat{K Q}
> $$
> by $L_{a^{-1}}(a p)=p, R_{a^{-1}}(p a)=p$, and $L_{a^{-1}} (p^{\prime}) = 0 = R_{a^{-1}} (p^{\prime \prime})$ for all paths $p, p^{\prime}, p^{\prime \prime}$ such that $p^{\prime}$ and $p^{\prime \prime}$ do not start, respectively, end with $a$.
> Composing these maps, we obtain the cyclic derivative
> $$
> \partial_{a}=L_{a^{-1}} \circ \sigma=R_{a^{-1}} \circ \sigma: J_{\widehat{K Q}} / \operatorname{com}_{Q} \rightarrow \widehat{K Q}
> $$
> We also define
> $$
> \partial_{(a, b)}=L_{b^{-1}} \circ R_{a^{-1}} \circ \sigma=R_{a^{-1}} \circ L_{b^{-1}} \circ \sigma: J_{\widehat{K Q}}^{2} /\left(J_{\widehat{K Q}}^{2} \cap \operatorname{com}_{Q}\right) \rightarrow \widehat{K Q}
> $$
> A **potential** is an element $W \in J_{\widehat{K Q}}^{2} /\left(J_{\widehat{K Q}}^{2} \cap \operatorname{com}_{Q}\right)$. We call $(Q, W)$ a quiver with potential (QP).

> [CLUSTER CATEGORIES FOR ALGEBRAS OF GLOBAL DIMENSION 2 AND QUIVERS WITH POTENTIAL, CLAIRE AMIOT](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.1035.pdf) **3.1. Ginzburg dg algebra**. Let $Q$ be a finite quiver. An element $W$ of $k Q /[k Q, k Q]$ is called a **potential** on $Q$. It is given by a linear combination of cycles in $Q$.

Are these two definitions the same? Thank you.